# how to find all elements which class id matches a html value?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML

```
 <div class="poster-id"> pi-1</div>
```

then this HTML

```
 <div class="replies">
  <div class=" pi-1">...</div>
  <div class=" pi-2">...</div>
  //etc
 </div>
```

The poster id isn't the same on each page load, but the replies content is.

I'm trying to add an active class to all replies which match the poster value.

So I am trying something like

```
$('.replies').find('.' +$('.poster-id').text()).addClass('active');
```

this doesn't work.

This does work

```
$('.replies').find('.pi-1').addClass('active');
```

but the poster id needs to be a variable which, so I need to use ('.poster-id').text(), but whatever I try doesnt work.

Is the Jquery wrong?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$('.poster-id').text()` includes the leading space character, so your selector becomes `. pi-1` which is different from the `.pi-1` that you wanted (and IIRC is just invalid).

A possible solution would be to `.trim()` the text before turning it into a selector; perhaps even better would be to use an attribute instead of the element contents to store the "target class", e.g.:

```
<div id="data-poster-id-holder" data-poster-id="pi-1" />
```

And then

```
var className = $("#data-poster-id-holder").attr("data-poster-id");
$('.replies').find('.' + className).addClass('active');
```